# Android Navigation, I can move any fragment which is not connected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use the Navigation architecture component in my toy app.

First I drew the fragments relationship in my "nav_graph.xml".

For example, I drew 3 fragments A, B, and C like below:

A -> B -> C

So I have 2 actions:

- action_a_to_b
- action_b_to_c

In general, I use the below code to move another fragment.

In A fragment,

```
findNavController().navigate(ADirections.actionAToB())
```

In B fragment,

```
findNavController().navigate(ADirections.actionBToC())
```

But you may know, there is another way to navigate.
The fragment id can be used to navigate directly like below:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.a)
```

In my case, I don't have the action for A to C fragment.
But if I use the below code in my A fragment, I can navigate!

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.c)
```

Is it a bug? or intented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional as per the [documentation for `navigate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigate(int)):

> This supports both navigating via an [action](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDestination.html#getAction(int)) and directly navigating to a destination.

If you're using [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args), then only actions are supported. This ensures that you're only using the connections you've specified in your graph.

Comment: If it is possible to move another fragment which not connected, why should we use "nav_graph.xml"?  "nav_graph.xml" looks like meaningless. Yes, only in case of using Safe args, it has a good meaning.

Comment: nav_graph is graphical and easy to manage that's why some people prefer it. And the ID you use to navigate is also generated by nav_graph.

Comment: fragments are not connected but they all are live inside same navController.

Comment: The graphical Navigation Editor in Android Studio and Safe Args are both built off of the navigation XML, but you can certainly create your navigation graph programmatically (we have a Kotlin DSL for exactly that) and skip the XML if you have a valid use case (such as a server driven navigation graph).

Comment: I think that the navigating to the Fragment which not connected by the action should be blocked. If the developer wants to navigate to the fragment which not connected, he/she have to connect it in nav_graph.xml. Just my opinion.

Comment: yoonhok, if a fragment not connected to navGraph (maybe same navGraph) we can't call it.

Comment: I mean, the fragment not connected by action.

Comment: Maybe, there's no drawback if we use fragment ID instead of action. And some situations like startDestination we don't need to create a action first just call it with the ID of fragment.

Comment: Use Safe Args exclusively if you want that behavior.